# Apache James Spring distribution not starting

Tags: java, spring, james

Trying out the [Apache James](https://james.apache.org/) mail server at the moment. After I downloaded the [current binary distribution 3.4.0](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/james/server/3.4.0/james-server-app-3.4.0-app.zip) ("for Spring wiring"), I got the following behaviour when I ran:

```
bin\james.bat
```

Log (formatted for readability):

```
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
(...)
jvm 1    | ERROR 21:30:39,649 |
           org.apache.james.mailetcontainer.lib.AbstractStateMailetProcessor      
           Unable to init mailet WithPriority
jvm 1    | org.apache.mailet.MailetException: 
           Could not load mailet (WithPriority) (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
           'priority' init parameter is compulsory)
(...)
```

What's up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the [answer](https://gitter.im/apache/james-project?at=5d9fe9ed809de9699f1841ee) - try this:

> I will raise the issue up to the project meanwhile a quick fix to make that mailet
>   work:
>
> - in the James app folder, open the file conf/mailetcontainer.xml
> - find the mailet with class WithPriority
> - replace the xml tag <value>8</value> by <priority>8</priority>
> - try to run james server again

Looks like this in `conf/mailetcontainer.xml`:

```
(...)
<mailetcontainer enableJmx="true">
  <processors>
    <processor state="root" enableJmx="true">
      <mailet match="All" class="PostmasterAlias"/>
      <mailet match="RelayLimit=30" class="Null"/>
      <mailet matcher="All" class="WithPriority">
        <priority>8</priority>
      </mailet>
(...)
```