# Apache james 3.4 message spooled but not delivered

Tags: java, james

Installed apache james 3.4 on my local machine. Tried sending a smtp email , enabled debug mode in logs , I can see that email was received and sent to spool but it does not really go to database or get stored anywhere. Could see below logs after an email was sent:

DEBUG 14:40:22,520 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.DataLineJamesMessageHookHandler | executing james message handler org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.esmtp.MailSizeEsmtpExtension@139346fe
DEBUG 14:40:22,523 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.DataLineJamesMessageHookHandler | executing hook org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.log.HookResultLogger@7e0a3d14
DEBUG 14:40:22,523 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.DataLineJamesMessageHookHandler | executing hook org.apache.james.smtpserver.jmx.HookResultJMXMonitor@7727309d
DEBUG 14:40:22,526 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.DataLineJamesMessageHookHandler | executing james message handler org.apache.james.smtpserver.AddDefaultAttributesMessageHook@2ecd38f
DEBUG 14:40:22,527 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.DataLineJamesMessageHookHandler | executing hook org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.log.HookResultLogger@7e0a3d14
DEBUG 14:40:22,527 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.DataLineJamesMessageHookHandler | executing hook org.apache.james.smtpserver.jmx.HookResultJMXMonitor@7727309d
DEBUG 14:40:22,528 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.DataLineJamesMessageHookHandler | executing james message handler org.apache.james.smtpserver.SendMailHandler@e301d29
DEBUG 14:40:22,528 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.SendMailHandler | sending mail
INFO  14:40:22,567 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.SendMailHandler | Successfully spooled mail Mail1584042022511-573e00a5-df5c-4bd0-a9d2-0d4e45e12b0d from MaybeSender{mailAddress=Optional[kart2@kmart.com]} on 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1 for [kart2@kmart.com]
DEBUG 14:40:22,568 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.DataLineJamesMessageHookHandler | executing hook org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.log.HookResultLogger@7e0a3d14
DEBUG 14:40:22,569 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.DataLineJamesMessageHookHandler | executing hook org.apache.james.smtpserver.jmx.HookResultJMXMonitor@7727309d
DEBUG 14:40:22,583 | org.apache.james.mailetcontainer.impl.JamesMailSpooler | ==== Begin processing mail Mail1584042022511-573e00a5-df5c-4bd0-a9d2-0d4e45e12b0d ====
DEBUG 14:40:22,584 | org.apache.james.mailetcontainer.lib.AbstractStateCompositeProcessor | Call MailProcessor root
DEBUG 14:40:22,587 | org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer | Starting producer: Producer[direct://processor.root]
DEBUG 14:40:22,588 | org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache | Adding to producer cache with key: direct://processor.root for producer: Producer[direct://processor.root]
DEBUG 14:40:22,591 | org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache | >>>> direct://processor.root Exchange[]
DEBUG 14:40:22,610 | org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor | Done sequential processing 1 exchanges
DEBUG 14:40:22,616 | org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor | Done sequential processing 1 exchanges
DEBUG 14:40:22,617 | org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor | Done sequential processing 1 exchanges
DEBUG 14:40:22,618 | org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor | ExchangeId: ID-WW-CFT2PV2-1584041951079-0-9 is marked to stop routing: Exchange[ID-WW-CFT2PV2-1584041951079-0-9]
DEBUG 14:40:22,618 | org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor | Done sequential processing 1 exchanges
DEBUG 14:40:22,619 | org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline | ExchangeId: ID-WW-CFT2PV2-1584041951079-0-1 is marked to stop routing: Exchange[ID-WW-CFT2PV2-1584041951079-0-1]
DEBUG 14:40:22,637 | org.apache.james.mailetcontainer.impl.JamesMailSpooler | ==== End processing mail Mail1584042022511-573e00a5-df5c-4bd0-a9d2-0d4e45e12b0d ====

Any help is appreciated. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

I've also been having this issue and found that commenting out the following section in the default conf/mailetcontainer.xml configuration file did the trick.

```
        <mailet matcher="All" class="WithPriority">
            <value>8</value>
        </mailet>

        <mailet matcher="HasPriority=8" class="Null"/>
        <mailet matcher="AtLeastPriority=8" class="Null"/>
        <mailet matcher="AtMostPriority=8" class="Null"/>
```

It looks like this stops mail getting beyond the root processor.

I had initially followed this advice to get the server running [Apache James Spring distribution not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58493087/apache-james-spring-distribution-not-starting) but this seems to be more relevant [Re: Getting Apache James 3.4 to process mail.](https://www.mail-archive.com/server-user@james.apache.org/msg16194.html)

Comment: I moved to apache james 3.3 that seems to be working. Will try this and let you know.